# Is Metadata.CustomMetadata and Metadata.Operations available in Essentials and/or Professional edition?

Tags: metadata, custom-metadata

I can't really find much on the subject - is `Metadata.Operations` and `Metadata.CustomMetadata` available in Salesforce Professional and/or Essentials?

I know that simply selecting metadata like so `[Select Id, My_Field__c FROM MyType__mdt];` definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

I [found this guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/224/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/custom_metadata_types_impl_guide.pdf) that states custom metadata is available in Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer.

According to the [developer documenation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_editions.htm):

> To use Metadata API, your organization must use Enterprise Edition, Unlimited Edition, Performance Edition, or Developer Edition.

It does look like you can request Metadata API access for Professional Edition:

> ISV partners can request Metadata API access to Professional Edition orgs for apps that have passed the AppExchange Security Review. Access is granted through an API token (client ID). This special key enables the app to make Metadata API calls to customers’ Professional Edition orgs.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from that whether `Metadata.Operations` is actually Metadata API, since it is just an Apex class we are calling now? I understand that for older access via apex-mdapi (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) you would need that, but is that needed for `Metadata.Operations`?

Comment: That's a good point. [Developer documentation for Operations Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm) has some examples with Metadata.Operations. Try to run one of the examples in one of those SF editions if possible.